# How to extract value from string (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

**How to extract this string (RUBY)**

```
str = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)"
```

**My expect.**

```
r= 255  
g= 0  
b= 0  
alpha= 0.5
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-scan) with a tiny regular expression is your friend:

```
r, g, b, alpha = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)".scan(/[\d.]+/)
r # => "255"
g # => "0"
b # => "0"
alpha # => "0.5"
```

How it works is left for you to figure out. The [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-scan) documentation will help you as will the [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

this is possibly what you want.

```
r,g,b,alpha = str.match(/\((.+)\)/)[1].split(",").map(&:to_f)
```